# How can I remove a value from my session array which is displayed within a table?

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

I have created an array within a session which I have sucessfully managed to place into a table. It is effectively just a list of favourties that a user can create by clicking a button on a product page.

However, I want to create a button next to each product in the table which removes the product from the array and I cannot work out why it isn't working.

Here is my code: **(updated)**

```
    <?php
            if (isset($_POST['remove'])) {
            $value_to_delete = 'JX-1E1-LTU';
            if(($key = array_search($value_to_delete, $_SESSION['arr'])) !== false) {
                unset($_SESSION['arr'][$key]);
                $_SESSION["arr"] = array_values($_SESSION["arr"]);
                    }
            }           
        ?>

         <?php

            $contents = ($_SESSION['arr']);
            $arrlength = count($contents);

                echo '<table class="table table-striped equipment">';
                echo '<thead>';
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th scope="col">';
                echo 'Parts';
                echo '</th>';
                echo '<th scope="col">';
                echo 'Remove Item';
                echo '</th>';
                echo '</tr>';
                echo '</thead>';
                echo '<tbody>';                 
                for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) 
                {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $contents[$x];                     
                    $part = $contents[$x];                      
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';                        
                    $pos = array_search($part, $contents);    
                    echo ' ' . $pos;                                    
                ?>  
                <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="value" value="<?php echo $part;?>">
                <input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove">
                </form>         
                <?php                       
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';                   
                }                   
                echo'</tbody>';
                echo '</table>';
?>
```

The 'deleteall' button works at the bottom of the page - it successfully removes all the values from my session, but the 'remove' button isn't removing each product individually:

```
            if (isset($_POST['remove'])) {
                $key=array_search($_GET[$part],$_SESSION['arr']);
                if($key!==false)
                unset($_SESSION['arr'][$key]);
                $_SESSION["arr"] = array_values($_SESSION["arr"]);
            }

            echo '<form action="" method="post">';
            echo    '<input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove">';
            echo '</form>';
```

I'm guessing I am doing something wrong in the above section, but I seemed to have hit a brick wall and tried everything I can think of, any help would be gratefully recevied!

Comment: where should `$_GET['anypart']` come from? The form's action is empty, method is POST, so no $_GET is sent/received

Comment: possible sollution: add a hidden input in that remove-form that holds the "part" (which you will then find in `$_POST`, not in `$_GET`)

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your help. So, you mean change the $_GET to $_POST after 'array_search'? and then add a hidden field before the submit field with a value of $part? If so I have tried this but it isn't working.. Could you provide example code of what you mean. Thanks

Comment: @Jeff I played around with this a bit and had it working exactly how I intended (see update to question). However, once I had tested it by re-adding more products to the list it no longer worked? Do I need to use session_write_close after the isset $_POST['remove'] code? Feel like I am getting close now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sample seems to imply you're executing the `remove` action right before the form display, so after having displayed the table. It won't work on the first page refresh.

So unless the remove action code is not in the right place, Try this piece of code below, which works here.

Use it first as a single file. Follow the instructions, and see if you can reproduce your issue. If not, it might be related to the environment.

Then, put the block code before displaying your `table` (and edit the `$_SESSION["arr"]` with correct values :)), and see if it removes the right element from the array.

If it doesn't, try debugging it through logging.

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "<pre>";

// Load this page once. Then, before the next page refresh,
// Comment the below line to check if the session values
// are updated

$_SESSION["arr"] = array("trousers", "blue", "jean");
print_r($_SESSION);

unset($_SESSION["arr"][array_search("blue", $_SESSION["arr"])]);
print_r($_SESSION);

$_SESSION["arr"] = array_values($_SESSION["arr"]);
print_r($_SESSION);

echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful. I have updated the code in the question. I now have it working... however I need to work out how to call the $part var instead of what is currently manually entered as 'JX-1E1-LTU'. When I type the part number in it works, but I need it to 'read' this from the form. I beleive the problem is that the  $part = $contents[$x]; is set after the remove action. Is there a way I can somehow call it before?! Thanks

Comment: You can retrieve the values submitted from `$_POST` array, since you submit them through the post method. You can display its content with `print_r()` you already know. You'll see it stored in `$_POST["value"]` the input text element is named `"value"`. I don't see why you use `$part` here, you should use another variable. (NB : ensure `$_POST["value"]` is set before using it, with `isset()`).